# Is it possible to use/query data using Pig/Tableau or some-other tool from HDFS which was inserted/loaded using a HIVE Managed table?

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-pig, hiveql

Is it possible to use or query data using Pig or Drill or Tableau or some other tool from HDFS which was inserted/loaded using a HIVE Managed table; or is it only applicable with data in HDFS which was inserted/loaded using a HIVE External table?

Edit 1: Is the data associated with Managed Hive Tables locked to Hive?

Answer (score 1):

Managed and external tables only refer to the file system, not visibility to clients. Both can be accessed with Hive clients

Answer (score 0):

Hive has [HiveServer2](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/hive/hiveserver2+overview) (use Thrift) which is a service that lets clients execute queries against Hive. It provides JDBC/ODBC.

So you have query data in hive however it is managed table by hive or external tables.

DBeaver/Tableau can query hive once connected to HiveServer2.

For Pig you can use [HCatalog](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HCatalog+LoadStore)

> pig -useHCatalog